# Rails modeling admin-controlled fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 10 drop-down fields in a "post" form that I want to be controlled by the admin user.

Currently, I have another model called "post fields"

```
class PostField
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :family, type: String
  field :project, type: String
  field :event, type: String
  field :testmode, type: String
  field :location, type: String
end
```

I then use these documents to populate each dropdown for a new post.

I have 2 dilemmas:

1. If the admin adds a PostField document for one dropdown, it creates a whole document. Not the most efficient thing, but I can deal with that.
2. If the admin changes the name of a field, all associated posts won't match.

This is effectively a tagging model, but poorly implemented b/c I'm not sure how to do it.

ie, I want to have a controlled list of locations: ["Upstairs", "Downstairs", "Bathroom"] so users can't just use a text input and say "Restroom" instead. But if an admin wants to change "Bathroom" to "Restroom", I want the posts to update accordingly.

Hope this isn't too complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want each PostField to be of a certain type, or location? So you want to limit the values that go into :location?

What you have to do is create another model and table called locations, and that will contain a list of locations like Upstairs, Downstairs, Bathroom, etc. It has and id, and a name. In your PostField, you will join to the Locations with `has_one :location`, and the database table will have `location_id`. Then the admin can change Location.name to anything they want, while all the PostFields will show the updated label. In the view, use `postField.location.name` to display the label for that field.

Comment: So, if I have 10 fields, I'll have 10 models? :/

Comment: Yes. There may be a way to create static models without using the database, but I've not had to do that yet. Then you could just change the source code to rename the fields.

Comment: You could also have a multi-key join to a single model. Then you would reference it the same way but the scope(?) would find the values in the other table. The table would have key1, key2, name. I've also not had to use that either, but I'm sure it's possible.

Comment: Exactly what I was about to suggest. (+1) In addition you can allow your admin to add or remove items from the list of available options. Meaning your admin can add "Toilet" and have four options (provided you set up the interface to allow adding and deleting in addition to modifying). IMO setting up 10 small models to allow an admin this level of control is pretty trivial, the interface already implemented will have been more work!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to anderstand what you want to do.

With this schema, you should be able to create a "post" with static fields and dynamic fields.

[image: simple schema]

**PostField**

- The "sorting" field is used to sort post's field with respect to each other.
- The "code" field will contain the code to identify post's field. Once created, it should be static.
- *If you want to make it dynamic, you should add a field "label" so administrator can add new post's field*

**PostFieldValue**

- The "sorting" field is used to sort values with respect to each other.
- The "label" field is in your example ["Upstairs", "Downstairs", "Bathroom"]

**In model**

You should create a method to get the value based on post's field.

**Improvements**

- You can improve the schema by adding a "isdefault" field to values so administrator can force the default value in drop-down.
- You can categorize post's field if needed